# Displaying dynamic text with hyperlinks in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I have an application that should work a bit like a message board: text gets parsed, hyperlinks are made "live" and displayed. Only it's in Silverlight. Because of that, I can't use TextBlock like they do here [WPF - Making hyperlinks clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861409/wpf-making-hyperlinks-clickable), somehow it's different in Silverlight and it's not possible to do a Hyperlink with a Run inside it.

I've tried the RichTextBlock, as it says here [Wrapping Text and Hyperlinks in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793601/wrapping-text-and-hyperlinks-in-silverlight), but couldn't for the life of me figure out how to create the paragraphs and hyperlinks from code, since I need to populate it dynamically.

Then I thought I'd settle for a less elegant solution involving TextBlocks and HyperlinkButtons in a WrapPanel. I added a namespace reference, like it says here [WrapPanel in Silverlight 4 toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988744/wrappanel-in-silverlight-4-toolkit), but when I reference it in XAML, there's no WrapPanel in it, only DataField, DataForm and VisualStateManager.

This [Text areas and hyperlinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691783/text-areas-and-hyperlinks) doesn't work either, the Silverlight RichTextBox is different and LinkLabel is missing.

Maybe there's another solution that I don't know? I'm keeping an open mind. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The only workaround I've been able to find so far is to create a StackPanel of TextBlocks and HyperlinkButtons, so that every link is a separate line.